# can I put a nodejs+express app to static website?

Tags: node.js, web

I have a website domain and have a static portfolio website. 
Then, I made a small program with NodeJS + Express by using APIs.

My question is that, how can I link my program to my website? I only linked to my gitHub repo but I want to actually have the program on my website as well so people can try it.

I was thinking about it and I could think that maybe I should re-create my portfolio website by using NodeJS + Express and route from there to my program...

Any help/tip I'll appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @Pigletwithcurls, that's a pretty broad question, you might wanna do some more research. The first thing to know is what the current setup for your website is? (PHP? WordPress? Some PASS (like heroku)?) Of course, re-creating your portfolio website with Node and Express can work.

Comment: hi @FelDev, thanks for the reply. My portfolio website is just a simple one with HTML and CSS. Then, my program is with nodejs, express, hbs, css, js. I am wondering if it's possible to put my program onto my website(that only has html and css). My website doesn't have any backend, so I was wondering if I should add backend to it. I'm novice to web development.

Comment: To run server-side code, you need a web server.

Comment: @Slaks, thanks for comment. So in order to put up my nodejs+express program on my webiste, my website should have backend I guess? I think I should do that then. I was wondering if there's any other way. Thank you!

Comment: Like @Slaks said, you need a web server.
We're still waiting on the <node-app></node-app> HTML tag 

Comment: @FelDev, Oh my god. I think that's what I was wondering. Thank you for your help.